# If there are several fixed effects of interest, and I want to test their inclusion via LRTs, in what order should I test them?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, model-comparison, clinical-trials

I have various potential fixed effect predictors for a linear mixed effect model. Some are control variables and some are predictors of interest (on their own and interactions). I am interested in testing the inclusion of certain predictors of interest using LRTs.

In what order should I test the predictors? Should I start with the ones I am most interested in? Should I start with main effects and then test interactions?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter in what order you test them. However I would just make a few points:

- avoid stepwise procedures. There are many resources on this site and elsewhere that go into detail about why.
- you should adjust your p values for multiple testing.
- it is better to let clinical/expert knowledge determine which variables to include and not be guided by statistical significance, due to the arbitrariness of significance levels. See the first part of my answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473954/intercept-interpretation-in-multi-level-model-when-first-level-predictor-discret).
- regarding interactions, in particular, you should include the relevant main effects when you include an interaction. That is, don't include an interaction without the main effects.

Comment: @Dave if this answers your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer